open excel file because I know the password of it
I have excel file and I encrypted it with password 123 to protect it, and I want to open this file in c#, but when I open it by {
Process .Start("Book11.xlsx);

it  was opened but ask the user to enter password and I want to write the password in c sharp code to not ask the user to enter password

as il code can be easy recovered, why use a password

I think this will answer your questions: Open EXCEL (.xlsx) with password in C#
